# How to extract/recognize text from documents?

Tags: php, pdf, ms-word, ocr, lamp

I need to extract plain text from uploaded documents in order to make them searchable. Documents could be MS Word or pdf (either scanned or containing text). The application in question is running on a LAMP stack, but installing other software could be an option. Is there any tool, service, library or combination of those that you could recommend to accomplish this task?

Comment: For scanned documents I think you'll need a bit of [OCR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition)

Comment: Extracting text from old-style .doc files is a serious pain. They're not meant to be easily parsable. .docx is somewhat easier, as they're just zipped .xml files for the most part.

Comment: @BlotClock I know. I did not mention it explicitly, because I assumed it was obvious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a combination of shell utilities like `pdftotext` for PDFs, `wvWare` for DOCs, `docx2txt.pl` for DOCX's, like the [textractor](https://github.com/mguterl/textractor/tree/master/lib/textractor/extractors) rubygem does.

```
# on Ubuntu
apt-get install wv xpdf-utils links
```

There are also native php classes for extracting [PDF](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/6155-PHP-Extract-text-from-PDF-files.html) and [docx](http://www.botskool.com/geeks/how-extract-text-docx-or-odt-files-using-php).

Another rubygem, which even does OCR for you though Tesseract, is [docsplit](http://documentcloud.github.com/docsplit/).

It might be a good idea to consider [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/) for indexing and searching. You may use the [Solr Cell](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/ExtractingRequestHandler) plugin to index and search Word documents, PDF's and more. I use it successfully  in one of my projects. Solr Cell is based on several projects like Apache [POI](http://poi.apache.org/), [Tika](http://tika.apache.org/) and [PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/).

The tricky part is to set up all the cell dependent jars and solr schema, and to figure out the indexing request parameters, but all can be thought out from the wiki documentation.  [Here's](https://gist.github.com/1219341) my jars and schema to get you started, the relevant part of the schema is the line containing "attachment".

Solr Cell does not do OCR, though. You will have to use an OCR Engine first to make them searchable.

For OCR you can use the OpenSource Engine Tesseract, which is developed by Google or you might want to have a look at the commercial engine [Abbyy](http://www.ocr4linux.com/en%3astart). Both come as commandline utils, which you can run from your php scripts. To get the comparable results from Tesseract as from Abbyy, you will have to do some pre- and postprocessing [1](http://groups.google.com/group/tesseract-ocr/browse_thread/thread/8bfd74d94d8638d8?pli=1). There are also cloud services, which might be an easier option. For instance, [Wisetrend](http://www.wisetrend.com/wisetrend_ocr_cloud.shtml) and [Abbyy Cloud](http://www.ocrsdk.com/). The latter is in beta at the moment, so it's free of charge and it has ready-to-go [PHP code samples](https://github.com/abbyysdk/ocrsdk.com/blob/master/PHP/abbyy_php_example.php).

Comment: Does Solr Cell have OCR to extract text from scanned PDF's?

Comment: I am not sure at all, but I think not. I believe the OCR should be done further up the pipeline, and I heard that [tesseract](http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/) is a great free tool to do that with.

Comment: Then it just won't work for scanned PDF's. They should be converted first to searchable PDF's (with added text layer) by some OCR software.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer was prolly the most helpful one. I realize the question was a little broad, so there is not really a definitive answer. I edited in some info about OCR and made it an answer wiki, so other people can contribute stuff as well.

Answer (score 3):

As far as i'm concerned, there's not much you can do with OCR on PHP. The best solution would be using a cloud service - a web api that lets you upload an image and send you back an OCR'ed data. Try [www.ocrsdk.com](http://www.ocrsdk.com/), it is a cloud based OCR SDK recently launched by ABBYY. It's now in beta so it's completely free to use and it has ready-to-go [PHP code samples](https://github.com/abbyysdk/ocrsdk.com/blob/master/PHP/abbyy_php_example.php). Disclamer: i work @ ABBYY

Comment: Interesting! Since this is only part of the solution, though, I edited the other answer instead (edit is still pending). I hope you forgive me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any software that converts PDF to text, but for the MS Word part, you can use the Apache POI: http://poi.apache.org/ which is built in JAVA so you would have to execute the binary from your PHP file to make it work.

Another option is to use the JODConverter (which I'm currently using for this purpose) http://code.google.com/p/jodconverter/
So if the Apache POI doesn't work, I know the jodconverter does. I'm using the 3.0 beta.

In my PHP code, I'm saving the uploading file and executing the converter binary on the file in the tmp directory, which will create a new file in the tmp directory and I pull the plain text from the new file.

Comment: Note: it is maybe more efficient to input the file via stdin, so you don't have to save it to disk first. If the uitility in question does not provide a cli switch for this, you can use /dev/stdin under Linux.